# Code Design Pattern Structure

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a dilemna that needs I've been thinking a while but still haven't figured it out how to **effectively** and **efficiently** code (design) it.

I have object data that get returns in 3 text-based formats: JSON, XML, ATOM. In JSON, the data can be a JSON Object or JSON array. XML and ATOM are xml.

Based on these 3 formats, I have to create objects (let's say A, B, C, D, E). I thought of having a Builder Pattern to generate these objects, so my interface builder is:

```
public interface Builder<T, E, A> { //Where E = Element, A is Element array, this is useful for JSON
   public T create(E element);
   public T[] create(A array);
}

public class ABuilder implements Builder<A, JSON, JSONArray> {
  public A create(JSON json) {...}
  public A[] create(JSONArray array) {...}
}
```

The problem is that I want to create a dynamic Factory/Alternative design pattern that can create an object based on the format....

i.e. I want a functionality such that, I can do

```
public class Resource {

   public A getA(String formatString) {
      return new Something().createA(formatString); //or something better....
   }
}
```

Do you have any better way of making this issue possible? Bear in mind, all this is based on the 3 possible formats. The goal is to generate objects dynamically based on the format, without really worrying about the format structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you need, but the first design pattern that came to my mind was [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

with this simple and elegant pattern, you can implement a concrete strategy for each implementation you have (xml, json, atom) and you also have a flexible solution that can be easily extended in the future to support new formats without breaking any existing code (that is the Open-Close principle).

so, you would have a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that would provide a "Build"/"Get" method which input would be an enum representing the required format (just an example, you can implement any way you want), and that factory method would use a strategy to actually build the object. that way, the client is 100% unaware of how the object is built, and doesn't even have to know what format it is.

good luck!

Comment: I thought of the same thing. What I'm trying to get here, is that based on the format, e.g. the JSON strategy, I can potentially get a json array (which starts and ends with a `[` and `]` respectively or a JSON object, which starts and ends with a `{` and `}` respectively). XML can, in essence have an array or an object (differentiated by the element name). I thought that builder was better for that scenario, but won't be optimal when used with strategy. You get my drift?

Comment: the builder pattern is useful when you have a complex process for building an object, with several different implementations. since you didn't describe the internal structure of the objects you build, I can't really say if it's useful. I agree it's also a valid direction - you can have concrete builder for each part of your object that know how to deal with JSON, XML, etc. \

Comment: the important thing whether you use strategy or builder is that you maintain the open/close principle and your design is flexible for future changes, and also encapsulated enough so that external components can use it without being affected when it is changed.

Comment: I've solved this issue with a Strategy (for XML, JSON and ATOM). Factory to return the Strategy and Template method to get the equivalent object required during object building. Thanks alot for clarifying my approach.